# Can a UI class with different Obj-C and Swift names be used in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, storyboard

I have a UIButton Swift subclass `CustomButton` and I would like to expose a prefixed name to Obj-C.

`@objc(PrefixCustomButton) public class CustomButton: UIButton { ... }`

This class exists in a Swift module `CustomModule`. I am integrating this module via Cocoapods into Objective-C and Swift apps to test `CustomButton`. When I try to use `CustomButton` from Storyboard, I get the following error:

`Unknown class _TtC9CustomModule17CustomButton in Interface Builder file.`

I have also tried using PrefixCustomButton in Storyboard and get the same error:

`Unknown class _TtC9CustomModule22PrefixCustomButton in Interface Builder file.`

Edit: @matt is correct in that `PrefixCustomButton` has to be used in Storyboard (for both Swift and Obj-C projects). The additional part I was missing was that I didn't need to set the Module name.

Comment: `@objc(PrefixCustomButton) CustomButton: UIButton { ... }` That is not Swift. Perhaps you mean `@objc(PrefixCustomButton) class CustomButton: UIButton { ... }`

Comment: Yup sorry, will edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it yourself: you have exposed a different name to Objective-C. So the class's name is PrefixCustomButton as far as Interface Builder is concerned.

Comment: If I use PrefixCustomButton, then I get "Unknown class _TtC9AppName22PrefixCustomButton in Interface Builder file."

Comment: Well, I don't. Something else must be going on.

Comment: This seems to work if I add the button as a UIView in Storyboard rather than a UIButton.

Comment: It's a UIButton in mine. I'd be amazed if it worked as a UIView; you can't turn a UIView into a working button just by casting it to a button. — Maybe your project is hosed. I'd start by clearing the caches, etc. That fact that you are getting the munged name of the class is unusual too; when I call mine CustomButton, my error still gives the correct name, "CustomButton", as the name of the troublesome class.

Comment: I have `CustomButton` in a Swift module that I'm integrating via Cocoapods into Swift and Objective-C projects where I'm trying to add it in Storyboard. What I'm seeing so far is adding a UIButton component in Storyboard and setting the custom class to `PrefixCustomButton` + setting module name, I get the aforementioned errors. When I add a UIView component and set the custom class to `PrefixCustomButton` and don't set a module name, it works.

Comment: Well, then you asked your question very badly, because you didn't mention any of that.

Comment: Sure, sorry, this is my first SO question. Updated original post to include the information I mentioned.